# How to get/create org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.BreakpointsMediator2

Tags: eclipse, debugging, plugins, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing Eclipse plugin which works with Debugger Services Framework (DSF). The goal I'm trying to achieve is to map `IBreakpointsExtension.IBreakpointHitDMEvent` to platform breakpoint `org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IBreakpoint`. There is service and function which can do exactly what I need: `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.BreakpointsMediator2#getPlatformBreakpoint`.

The question is how to get/create `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.BreakpointsMediator2` ?

I tried to call `DsfServicesTracker#getService(BreakpointsMediator2.class)` but it returns `null`.
There is another option (I guess) to create `BreakpointsMediator2` instance right in the place where it is going to be used. In that case we need instance of `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.IBreakpointAttributeTranslator2`. But `DsfServicesTracker#getService(IBreakpointAttributeTranslator2.class)` is also returns `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because eclipse-dsf-cdt project simply doesn't implement `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.BreakpointsMediator2` and `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.debug.service.IBreakpointAttributeTranslator2` interfaces. There are request though for implementation. Check https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478454.
Another possible solution is to use MIBreakpointsManager. Keep in mind that in this case your code depends on `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.mi.service`.